# Why calling times.cpuTime() is slow in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

In c++, `std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` takes about 20 nanos on my machine, which is close to `rdtsc` instruction. But in Nim, times.cpuTime (it calls clock_gettime in Linux) takes about 350ns. Any body knows why?

```
proc toNanos(sec: float): int64 =
  let SecInNano = 1000000000f64
  return (sec * SecInNano).int64

proc testTimes() =
  let N = 1000000
  var ts : seq[float]
  ts.setLen(N+1)
  for i in 0..N :
    ts[i]= cpuTime()

  var dur = toNanos((ts[N-1] - ts[0]) / N.float) 
  for i in 0..<N :
    ts[i] = ts[i+1] - ts[i]

  discard ts.pop
  ts.sort()
  echo fmt"---------- latency of invoking cpuTime (ns): nSamples: ", N, " ----------------"
  echo fmt"  Avg       Min       50%        90%       Max"
  echo fmt"  {dur}       {ts[0].toNanos}       {ts[N div 2].toNanos}       {ts[int(N.float*0.9)].toNanos}       {ts[N-1].toNanos}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that `std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` returns an int. Whereas `times.cpuTime()` converts the result to a float.
Using `monotimes.getMonoTime()` which returns an int, I get times of about 40ns.

```
import std/[algorithm, strformat, monotimes]

proc testTimes() =
  const N = 1000000
  var ts = newSeq[int64](N+1)

  for i in 0..N:
    ts[i] = getMonoTime().ticks

  var dur = int(float(ts[N-1] - ts[0]) / float(N))
  for i in 0..<N:
    ts[i] = ts[i+1] - ts[i]

  discard ts.pop
  ts.sort()
  echo fmt"---------- latency of invoking cpuTime (ns): nSamples: ", N, " ----------------"
  echo fmt"  Avg       Min       50%        90%       Max"
  echo fmt"  {dur}       {ts[0]}       {ts[N div 2]}       {ts[int(N.float*0.9)]}       {ts[N-1]}"

testTimes()
```

BTW: The next time please post a complete runnable example, it simplifies testing.

Comment: Thanks for looking int this. I've figured it out. times.cpuTime calls clock_gettime with CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID which makes it much slower than  calling clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC).

Comment: I did not expect the clock to make much difference, but it is plausible. Good to know.